# Default URL Mapping Secure Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have configured a simple secured single page web application like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class MvcConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                //.loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

With the `.loginPage("/login")` commented out, I get a default login page like the one below:
[image: no problems here]

Everything works as expected.

However, if I uncomment `.loginPage("/login")` to have it point to my  custom `login.html` page, I get a 404 Error.

This is my current file structure:

```
main
 L resources
    L static
        - index.html
        - login.html
```

I understand I can set the viewResolver using `XML` and configure every little thing under the sun, but I also understand Spring Boot has certain default settings I can take advantage of if I'm trying to make things as concise as possible.

My question is: Where is Spring looking for that `login.html` file? What is the absolute url where I must place my `login.html` file in order to avoid getting the 404 error?

*Also, if the solution must involve configuring spring in anyway, I would prefer to avoid XML and opt for Java based configuration if possible.*

Comment: have you any exception in the console? Have you a `ViewResolver`? I think the default location of thymeleaf templates is under resources -> templates

Comment: Hi @ManuZi, there are no errors in the console, only a 404 message by spring showing in the browser. I do not have a ViewResolver (I was hoping the auto config would take care of that). I have tried using the templates folder instead of the static but I still get the same result.

Comment: the last different i can so between yours and the spring io example is that you have a slash in the method. try something like this: `.loginPage("/login")`. Do you have the code from this page here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

So it turns out you can achieve the same result on spring boot by adding these two lines to `application.properties`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix = /WEB-INF/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix = .html
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

In case anyone else has a similar problem, here is what worked for me:

I had to create another class in addition to `MvcConfig` shown on the question:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

As you can see, this class has a Bean  with a viewResolver that will render any Thymeleaf templates you may have. It also adds the view controller for the login page and for the index page. Both where placed in the `templates` folder instead of the `static`.

This should work if you're trying to reproduce [this example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)